# How to adjust the frequency of the generated PWM signal from a TL494?

Tags: operational-amplifier, pwm, power-electronics, flipflop, inverting-amplifier

From the datasheet of TL494 IC, I have found that the frequency of the generated PWM signal for single ended mode is (f=1/(R×C)).

From the following figure, the frequency is constant to 10kHz or 10 us rather than what the values of the R and  C are. From the image, the time period  on the scope is 10us i.e 10k hz.

How do I adjust the frequency?

[image]

Comment: _”10us i.e 0.1 hz”_ Do you mean 100 kHz?

Comment: 1/ RC = 1 / (10 nF * 12 kohm) = 8.3 kHz, T = 1/f / 1 8.3 kHz = 120 us. The signal on the scope has a period of 10 divisions * 10us/div = 100 us. Only a 20% error. **Looks close enough to me**. Can you explain why you get 10 us and 0.1 Hz ?

Comment: Your 'scope shows 10 divisions at 10us/div - that's 100us which gives 10kHz. The formula in the datasheet predicts 8.333kHz for Rt=12k and Ct=10nF, so it's not that far off...

Comment: Sorry ..its constant to 10 khz..even if i change the values of Rand C to any value

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie sorry..the output frequency is constant to 10khz even if i change the values of R and C to any values

Comment: @brhans sorry..the output frequency is constant to 10khz even if i change the values of R and C to any values

Comment: 1) Change **one** thing at a time. 2) halve the value of R1 so make it 6 kohm. simulate again. If your waveform doesn't change, check that the netlist is re-created, that the waveform uses the correct data etc. If you did all as you should have then maybe there is something wrong in the model of the TL494

Comment: Then I'd guess that it's probably just a bad simulation of the TL494. Does the documentation for the simulator tell you anything about its simulated TL494 capabilities?

Comment: @brhans it is not supported by protues..but i have downloaded a protues library from the internet for it

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie ok i will try

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your model is probably "bad" or "bad use" (I see DTC is grounded ?, see my schematic, others things missed ?).

Here is a simulation with another simulator (operational test circuit from TI, datasheet of TL494).

In this model, frequency changes with R and/or C. In TRANS analysis, click on component and use arrows keys up or down.

Model of PWM-controller  TL494,
Developed by Sergey Amelin and Marina Amelina, 2008 http://www.spectrum-soft.com/index.shtm

Sample circuit, macro TL494.mac from microcap v12,

[image]